# I need to capture orderIds in array format from the Jmeter response and want to use it in next POST call

Tags: html, html-table, jmeter

I am not able to extract the orderIDs in array format. 
orderID 2072764,2072763,2072762,2072761,2072760,2072759,2072758 etc.

```
<tbody><tr class="row" data-href="/order/2072765">
        <td class="column checkbox"><input type="checkbox" disabled /></td>
        <td class="column wide"></td></tr> <tr class="row" data-href="/order/2072764">
        <td class="column checkbox"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="column wide"></td></tr> <tr class="row" data-href="/order/2072763">
        <td class="column checkbox"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="column wide"></td></tr> <tr class="row" data-href="/order/2072762">
        <td class="column checkbox"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="column wide"></td></tr> <tr class="row" data-href="/order/2072761">
        <td class="column checkbox"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="column wide"></td></tr> <tr class="row" data-href="/order/2072760">
        <td class="column checkbox"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="column wide"></td></tr> <tr class="row" data-href="/order/2072759">
        <td class="column checkbox"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="column wide"></td></tr> <tr class="row" data-href="/order/2072758">
        <td class="column checkbox"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="column wide"></td></tr> <tr class="row" data-href="/order/2072757">
        <td class="column checkbox"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="column wide"></td></tr><tr></tr></tbody>
        </table>
```

I tried with Regular expression extractor:- /order/(.+?)
BeanShell Sampler

```
str = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
log.info("Previous response is "+str);
var order=str.get(tr);
//log.info(str.get(tr));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the below:-

1. RegEx to fetch all values
   [image]
2. JSR223 post processor with below code:-

> ```
> List<Integer> var_OrderAr = new ArrayList()
>
> for (def i = 1; i <= ${var_Order_matchNr}; i++) {
>   var_OrderAr.add(vars.get("var_Order_" + i))
> }
> log.info "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"+var_OrderAr
>
> String formattedString = var_OrderAr.toString()
>     .replace("[", "")  //remove the right bracket
>     .replace("]", "")  //remove the left bracket
>
> log.info "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"+formattedString
>
> vars.putObject("formattedString", formattedString)
> ```

3. Pass created array variable like ${formattedString} in the second request
   [image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the below groovy code in JSR223 PostProcessor

```
def str = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
log.info("Previous response is "+str);
def pat = /\/order\/(.*)\"/
def mm = str =~ pat
if (mm){
    //log.info("order regex" + mm[0][1]);
    def ss = mm.size()
    def finList = []
    mm.each{
        finList.push('"' + it[1] + '"')
        log.info("id="+it[1])
    }
    def orderIDs = finList.join(",")
    log.info("finVal" + orderIDs)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Regex as below describe in below image.
   [Regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zDnx.png)
2. Add Debug sampler.
3. Run the script.
4. Open Debug sampler in View result tree
5. you can observe that "order_1_g1" contain the 1st order id, "order_2_g1" contain the 2nd order id and so on.
6. Now you can use these variable wherever you want to.

[Debugsampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvh8E.png)